# IF-then not work properly

Tags: visual-c++

Is this correct way? I have tried many ways, it seems that does not work properly

```
CString result;
result  = ExecuteExternalProgram(L"c.txt", L"t.txt");   // return a CString

if (result == _T("one"))
    MessageBox(NULL,result.GetBuffer(), L"one", MB_OK);
else
        MessageBox(NULL,result.GetBuffer(), L"two", MB_OK);
```

Comment: even though result is "one", it does not get into the first condition. it always jump to ELSE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C strings can't be compared with `==` -- `==` compares whether the result pointer is the same as the pointer to your translated string. They won't be equal. If you're going to use C strings, then you should use C string comparison functions:

```
if (0 == strcmp(result, _T("one")) /* ... */ else /* ... */
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use a **strcmp** and check if it works fine?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using MFC's CString which has an overloaded '=' operator so your if conditions are partially fine. However, you need to change code like this:

```
CString result;
result  = ExecuteExternalProgram(L"c.txt", L"t.txt");   // return a CString

if (result == CString("one"))
    MessageBox(NULL,result.GetBuffer(), L"one", MB_OK);
else
    MessageBox(NULL,result.GetBuffer(), L"two", MB_OK);
```